# Has Homo Sapiens Evolved or is the Theory of Behavioral Modernism Flawed? My Question Has Been Twice Put On Hold, Why?

Tags: support

> **Homo Sapiens Is, As Homo Sapiens Was**
>
> Author(s): John J. Shea
> Source: Current Anthropology, Vol. 52, No. 1 (February 2011), pp. 1-35
> Published by: The University of Chicago Press on behalf of Wenner-Gren Foundation for
> Anthropological Research / Stable URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/658067

I realize [my question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/has-humanity-evolved-since-its-advent-upon-the-world-stage/19949?noredirect=1#comment46198_19949) is *subjective*, which is the reason I posed it @ Philosophy *beta* rather than some other SE forum! I've reviewed our help topic, **Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions**, my edited question passes muster on **5 of the 6 criteria**. *Ergo*, by Philosophy *beta*'s own criteria, my question is certainly viable, *if not*, **Great**.

I am well into the process of composing/articulating my own philosophy, cosmology, religion, psychology, etc. My system has significant affinity with Integral Theory but I am ambivalent concerning certain *important* aspects of both. **I come to Philosophy beta seeking the community's assistance**. My problems, are as follows:

1. Is anthropology’s developmental map/timeline accurate, sufficiently complete? My doubts here concern certain data indicating that ancient civilizations with advanced technologies/mathematics/cosmologies possibly existed on Earth prior to currently accepted timelines, i.e., in Egypt, Antarctica, South America. These doubts make it impossible to wholeheartedly embrace orthodox conceptions regarding Phylogeny and Ontogeny. Integral Theory holds that when the Pyramids were built the average level of individual development was Mythic, whereas if the Pyramids were conceived/constructed by Homo sapiens that fact, in and of itself, cast doubt on Wilber’s assessment.
2. Integral Theory holds that the hunter-gatherer Yámana aborigines are less evolved than the agrarian-pastoralist Navaho who, in turn, are less evolved than the industrialized Nipponese(?). This taxonomy is highly deterministic, which makes me suspicious; and, having personal experience with members of each of the aforementioned peoples, I have doubts that they are less “evolved” than I am. Finally, I can’t overlook the fact that the minds that conceived of the theory fit into the category of Most Evolved, which on the one hand makes perfect sense (who else would have the intellectual capacity to find the pattern), but on the other hand can also be evidence of bias.
3. Like Integral Theory, my system (*currently*) holds that ontogeny recapitulates phylogeny, not precisely, but in an approximate manner. I must admit that I like the symmetry and elegance, but remain unconvinced. My Philosophy *beta* query is intended to elicit the thoughts of others on this issue. I don’t have an agenda. I have a dilemma.

My question isn't merely "anthropological." In the final analysis, all human knowledge of the phenomenal universe, or "objective" reality, is limited and conditioned by the sensory apparatus (or mechanical extensions) used to "***know***" that reality--apparatus which, while revealing certain facets of the reality simultaneously obscure others--and further mediated by the interpreting human psyche, calling into question the whole notion of "objectivity." The question then becomes, epistemological.

> "If Mother Culture were to give an account of human history...it would go something like this: 'The Leavers were chapter one of human history--a long and uneventful chapter. Their chapter of human history ended about ten thousand years ago with the birth of agriculture in the Near East. This event marked the beginning of chapter two, the chapter of the Takers. It's true there are still Leavers living in the world, but these are anachronisms, fossils--people living in the past, people who just don't realize that their chapter of human history is over.'" Ishmael, by Daniel Quinn (1992)

**What's wrong with my question?**

Answer (score 3):

Just because our title says "Philosophy" does not mean that any subjective question is suddenly on-topic! In fact, it's even more important here that questions are topical -- by which I mean, arise organically from your study of *philosophy* (rather than say, anthropology.)

However, and for whatever it's worth: "species thinking" about the human is occasionally taken up in philosophical letters; though of course it is often difficult to distinguish from the crassest racism. And on the other hand, there is a great deal of theoretical and cultural analysis into the historical and contemporary formations of racial nationalism and discrimination. (Things to investigate might include for instance: Reich's *[Mass Psychology of Fascism](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0374508844)*, Fanon's *[Wretched of the Earth](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0802141323)* and maybe for more contemporary thinking, Chatelet's recently-translated *[To Live and Think Like Pigs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0983216967)*.)

Finally just in passing: *questions* really should be focused on specific problems you are encountering in your study of philosophy -- i.e., not just advancing a position and asking what people might think about it! (That's an *answer* really already.) There are lots of places online where position-advocacy statements in search of feedback or criticism might be welcome but the Philosophy mainpage isn't it. Do keep in mind though that we have a chat space to try to capture things that don't fit well into questions/answers/comments (i.e., if you want to discuss something in an open-ended fashion and don't necessarily have a *specific* problem you're working on.)

Comment: While I appreciate your attention I am already well aware of your position. I was hoping to elicit response from others. Is that possible?

Comment: @LittleEva He speaks for the whole mod team. Further, community members tend to not react positively to rants and your question here reads like a rant.

Comment: @mixedmath - well it's good to hear from another member. I'm sorry you feel as you do regarding my OP, I'm a newcomer to SE in general and Pb in particular, so I'm still learning its conventions, and its politics. As to my appeal to Meta, I believe I have followed protocol. In an earlier comment Mr. Weissman asked me to edit my OP and provide some contextual background. I have done both. While I certainly can be a passionate defender of those things I believe in, characterizing my Meta appeal as a "rant" is excessive.

Comment: I'm not a mod. I just upvoted this answer though. I don't think your problem relates to the "politics" of philosophy.se. Rather, I think it's that you're not getting the Q&A model SE is built and how that works out in terms of philosophy. What we *can do* is answer technical interpretative questions articulated in general layman terms. What we *cannot* do is grade or critique diatribes or complex interpretations. We all do this voluntarily. In my day job, I get paid to deal with people's more complex problems (though not directly in philosophy right now).

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to get a grip with what you are struggling with here and from what I see you are concerned because you believe [a question you asked](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/has-humanity-evolved-since-its-advent-upon-the-world-stage) is in fact on topic for this site but it was instead put on hold.

As posed I agree that the question is not on-topic for Philosophy.SE. From reading what you wrote above, I can see how you think it applies to philosophy, and sure it does in a very broad sense, but in that sense it is not nearly narrow enough to meet our criteria. As Joseph pointed out, this isn't really a place for analyzing a multi-point theory someone has developed, but you can easily get around it if you ask multiple specific points about that theory as they relate to philosophy (in your case, probably logic).

We are pretty darn lenient here in terms of that, but what you wrote above is not specific enough in terms of what you want philosophers/logicians to critique, and the post you made on the forums appears to be about anthropology.

I hope that helps! :)

Answer (score -2):

> I submit what follows as an Answer rather than what it is, *in fact*, because it is too lengthy to fit into the standard Comment box. I apologize for the deviation but didn't know of an alternative.

Thank you, Stoic Fury, for your response. I appreciate the substance of your answer, as well as its tone. As you undoubtedly are aware, I'm new to SE, Philosophy beta, and (*apparently*) still trying to learn how to participate. I am beginning to understand what you (inclusive) mean by overly broad questions and I can see how that critique can apply to my OP. I have been laboring to distill the essence of my dilemma--I believe my edit of my OP was a step in that direction--truth is, I haven't quite known how to articulate what I was after and I guess that was evident. My above appeal is actually the first time I've managed to precisely articulate what has been (for the most part, unconsciously) troubling me on *paper*, so criticism of the OP has been deserved, and helpful. And I appreciate that.

I'm not asking for a "*multi-point analysis*," however. In an effort to provide some contextual background, *per* Mr. Weissman’s suggestion, I included in my Meta appeal a few of the doubts that give rise to my dilemma (*Are current western industrialized human populations actually more evolved than First Humans and current hunter/gather populations or are our current orthodox conceptions of phylogenetic evolution an example of a cultural and epistemological bias?*). I guess my question, as originally conceived/posted, and then as edited, could only be construed as anthropological. But it was never so limited in my own mind. As I struggled to make the question more accessible/acceptable to Philosophy *beta* I came to realize that the input I sought (as far as I could see) must resolve on questions of *how* and *what* is considered valid “*knowing*.”

Two final additions, if I may--the first, a suggestion--Meta decisions of an appeal of a (*single*) moderator’s decision are (or at least, give the impression that they are) more fair when answered/decided by a different moderator(s). I found it quite frustrating when my Meta appeal of Mr. Weissman’s original decision was handled by Mr. Weissman. That practice gives the appeal process the appearance of a lack of probity. And last--but not least--a comment: in two of the comments that follow Mr. Weissman’s answer of my appeal, that appeal is characterized as a “*rant*,” and then, a “*diatribe*.” I take exception to both and find such mischaracterizations insulting and unseemly. My appeal follows SE protocols, complies with the moderator’s request for context, links to relevant academic papers, quotes SE’s, "*Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions*", remains polite, and avoids personalizing the issue.

> **Rant**: (intransitive verb) 1: to talk in a noisy, excited, or declamatory manner; 2: to scold vehemently. **Diatribe**: 1: archaic: a prolonged discourse; 2: a bitter and abusive speech or piece of writing. **Synonyms**: tirade, harangue, jeremiad, philippic, *rant*.

Thank you, again, Mr. Fury (your "handle" is *oxymoronic*—-that’s *not* meant to insult). If you’ve any further suggestions I’m all ears, I mean eyes. :-)

Comment: Missed the notification for this answer so I am just reading it now (apologies). I agree with your points, and while you've done everything by the book here, the question still needs some work. Mostly, I think if you added *what you've come up with so far*, I think that would help focus the question enough to be valid. Regarding the closing moderator responding here, I guess I don't understand since all the mods (there are only 2 of us) responded. RE: "rant", I can't find those comments you mention, but if they are worded in a way a reasonable person would find rude, we can remove/edit them.

Comment: Thanks, @stoicfury - no problems, I've absorbed suggestions and I'm working on a reformulation that's a better fit for Pb. In the comments directly above your answer, if you look closely at the only two comments that have been upvoted, you'll find "rant" & "diatribe." To me, SF, those were disparaging characterizations. Though the label "rant" can be legitimately applied it cannot be legitimately applied to my submissions.

Comment: "Rant" is also misapplied and has become internet "code" which can be used when someone wants to marginalize someone else. I don't want these remarks removed and hidden, Mr. Fury, I want them exposed. I would think Pb wants the newest of its users given some latitude and handled with tolerance. Thank you for doing just that, @stoicfury

Comment: Oh I was looking on the main site. Here I think the terms might a bit strong but their use was reasonable. Language is interesting and people can take a lot from very little. To me I see the comments as written as dispassionate, impersonal, constructive criticism; if directed at me then my post must surely have been droning on and on too long or gone off on many tangents too much. I also am more familiar with those who wrote those comments, and they seem like kind folk, very helpful people. So I don't see it as mean-spirited as a newcomer might, but we do try to be mindful of these things. :)

Comment: OK. Your point is taken.

Comment: @LittleEva in regards to the use of "diatribe", I use it almost exclusively in the supposedly antiquated meaning. In professional philosophy, that's the meaning it has. I was surprised to learn the dictionary thinks it primarily has taken on a different meaning.

Comment: @virmaior, I was feeling a bit *put-out* during the time you are referring to. Feeling *ganged*-upon. I was looking for information related to the "dilemma" contained in my posted question. Criticisms relate to my literary style were particularly galling at the time. But it's 'all good,' as they say. No hard feelings. :-)